# Lua Object Oriented object IDs don't increment

Tags: oop, lua, love2d

I'm trying to create an object for LOVE that will give itself its own ID's. Basically, every time I create this object, it's self.id should increment by one. However, if instead I create 5 new objects in a row, then the ID will be 4 (because it starts at 0).

However, if I create my objects and then manually change the ID, it saves correctly and that object is no longer "tied" to the idcounter.

```
entities = {}
idcounter = 0

Entity = {id = -1, test=0}
function Entity:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.id = idcounter
    idcounter = idcounter + 1
    entities[idcounter] = self
    return o
end

function Entity:GetID()
    return self.id
end

function Entity:SetTest(v)
    self.test = v
end

function Entity:GetTest()
    return self.test
end

test = Entity:new()
test2 = Entity:new()

print(test:GetID())
print(test2:GetID())
test.id = 10
print(test:GetID())
print(test2:GetID())
for k,v in pairs(entities) do
    print(test)
end
test3 = Entity:new()
print(test:GetID())
print(test2:GetID())
for k,v in pairs(entities) do
    print(test)
end
```

which prints

```
1
1
10
1
table: 00789020
table: 00789020
10
2
table: 00789020
table: 00789020
table: 00789020
```

the table parts of which is especially frustrating as I'd like to be able to traverse the array of all the entities that I've made, but they all seem to point to the same entity.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are printing out the value of `test` in your loop. Not the value of `v` which is the entity for the current loop entry. `pairs` also doesn't guarantee a traversal order.

Comment: You are also setting `Entities.id` in the `:new()` function instead of `o.id` which is the entity you created.

Comment: Oh wow! I'm terribly embarrassed on that first count. Let me get the second part straight: self is the same as Entity? Changing the self.id to o.id fixes that first part, but changing the prints in the loops to `print(tostring(v) .. " " .. v:GetID())` makes them print the same tables codes and -1's.

Comment: Oh, fixed it. I also had `entities[idcounter] = self` which, as you pointed out, self ain't right. Thank you very much!

Comment: `self` is the first (implicit when the function is defined with `:` syntax) argument to the function. When calling `Entity:new()` (which is identical to `Entity.new(Entity)`) then `self` is `Entity`. When calling `test:GetId()` then `self` is `test`.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is with the meaning of `self` in the `new()` method. This actually refers to the Entity metatable rather than the object you're creating. So when you set `self.id`, you're setting the equivalent of a class field rather than an object field.

To rectify this you'll need to change this to set `o.id` to the counter then each object will get a different id. Incidentally, what is happening when `test.id = 10` worked is that you were setting the object's `id` to 10 which overrode the metatable's.

A second point is in regard to the `entities` table. Lua likes tables to either be 1-indexed arrays or dictionaries. By indexing from 0 and overriding indices you're making it do something in between so it's unlikely to do quite what you want. My suggestion is to separate out the `entity` list from the object's `id` so that you'll always be able to traverse `entities` as an array. The downside is that you'll not be able to do code such as `entities[id]` to retrieve the object with that id.

So from a code perspective:

```
function Entity:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    o.id = idcounter
    o.test = "test "..idcounter
    idcounter = idcounter + 1
    entities[#entities+1] = o
    return o
end

for k,v in ipairs(entities) do
    print(v.test)
end
```